# Download excel file on anchor tag with confirmation dialogue box in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to download excel file on confirmation of yes button from dialogue box

On click of button open a dialogue box and that ask are sure you want to download?
two buttons are provide yes and no.
On click of yes button from dialogue box method call from controller and excel file is download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/method'); ?>" onclick="return confirm('are sure you want to download?')">Download</a>`

By click on download link, a confirmation box will appears with two options ok and cancel. By proceeds with ok button, controller's method will be execute.